# Connection with RODBC

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am  having trouble with my query following an ODBC connection.
The connection seems to work, I can describe all tables

```
mycon<-odbcConnect("nicer_64") #OK
sqlTables(mycon) #OK
sqlColumns(mycon,"a_patient") #OK
sqlQuery(mycon, "DESCRIBE a_patient")

                     Field                Type Null Key Default          Extra
1                      PID    int(10) unsigned   NO PRI      NA auto_increment
2                 REF_EXT1         varchar(20)   NO          NA               
3                 REF_EXT2         varchar(20)   NO          NA               
4                  ARCHIVE tinyint(3) unsigned   NO MUL       1               
5             ARCHIVE_DATE            datetime  YES          NA               
6             ARCHIVE_USER         varchar(16)   NO          NA               
7                   LCKDAT            datetime  YES          NA               
8                  LCKUSER         varchar(16)   NO          NA               
9                     NAME         varchar(50)   NO MUL      NA               
10              LADIESNAME         varchar(50)   NO MUL      NA               
11              FIRSTNAME1         varchar(50)   NO MUL      NA               
12              FIRSTNAME2         varchar(50)   NO          NA               
13                    SEXE          tinyint(4)   NO MUL       0               
14               BIRTHDATE            datetime  YES MUL      NA               
15  BIRTHDATE_CI_VALIDATED          tinyint(1)   NO           0               
16    BIRTHDATE_INACCURACY              int(1)   NO           0               
17                 AVS_NBR         varchar(16)   NO MUL      NA               
18              AVS_STATUS              int(2)   NO MUL       0               
19       NAME_HISTORY_COPY        varchar(250)   NO MUL      NA               
20  FIRSTNAME_HISTORY_COPY        varchar(250)   NO MUL      NA               
21 LADIESNAME_HISTORY_COPY        varchar(250)   NO MUL      NA               
22  BIRTHDATE_HISTORY_COPY        varchar(250)   NO MUL      NA               
23                   STATE         varchar(10)   NO          NA               
24                   OFSID         varchar(10)  YES          NA               
25         OFS_UPDATE_DATE            datetime  YES          NA               
26         OFS_UPDATE_RESP         varchar(50)   NO          NA               
27               CITIZENID         varchar(16)   NO MUL      NA               
28       DIGITISATION_DATE            datetime  YES          NA               
29                 PAT_NBR             int(11)   NO UNI       0               
30      ANONYMISATION_DATE            datetime  YES          NA
```

but then when I do this query I get an error.

```
test<-sqlQuery(mycon,paste('SELECT "PID","NAME","FIRSTNAME1","SEXE","BIRTHDATE" FROM "a_patient";'))
head(test)

[1] "42000 1064 [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.22-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"a_patient\"' at line 1"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT \"PID\",\"NAME\",\"FIRSTNAME1\",\"SEXE\",\"BIRTHDATE\" FROM \"a_patient\";'"
```

Is it the SQL syntax that is wrong? Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove the quotes and the semi-colon

```r
test<-sqlQuery(mycon,paste('SELECT PID, NAME, FIRSTNAME1, SEXE, BIRTHDATE FROM a_patient')) # "" and ; removed
head(test)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally found the issue. It is related to  variables having dates as format.
When I remove "BIRTHDATE" it does work.
Otherwise I get this error message:
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...)